# Finding $A, B$ after splitting rational function

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus

I am revisiting integration. So, I had to solve this integral $$\int \frac{x + 13}{x^2 - 4x - 5}\,dx.$$ And I did.

Obviously, $x^2 - 4x - 5 = (x - 5)(x + 1)$ and now we want to write
$$\frac{x + 13}{x^2 - 4x - 5} = \frac{x + 13}{(x - 5)(x + 1)}$$
as a sum of two rational functions so we can use linearity, i. e. property
$$\int (f(x) + g(x))dx = \int f(x) dx + \int g(x)\,dx.$$

So, we want to find $A, B \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $$\frac{A}{x - 5} + \frac{B}{x + 1} = \frac{x + 13}{(x - 5)(x + 1)}$$

From this, it follows $A(x + 1) + B(x - 5) = x + 13$.

Now, my basic question.

Why exactly, for every $2$ $x$'s we choose we get the same $A, B$?

For example, $x = 5, x = - 1$ give $A = 3, B = - 2$. If we plug in $x = 100, 101$ we also get $A = 3, B = - 2$.

Same if we plug in any two real (different) numbers for $x$.
Why is this always true? Thanks.

Comment: This will be true because this is a system of two equations in disguise and isn't over or under constrained.

Comment: It's true because we want $A(x+1)+B(x-5)=x+13$ to be true for all $x$!

Comment: So, we are simultaniously solving infinite number of pairs of two equations with 2 unknown? Neat.

Comment: Rewrite the equation as $(A+B)x+(A-5B)=x+13$, and you can see it will hold for all $x$ provided $A+B=1$ and $A-5B=13$.

Comment: Very cool. So, this is true in general? If we have $n$ variables, say $A_1, A_2, ..., A_n$?

Comment: If you are asking in the context of partial fractions, and if you do the setup right, then, yes, it's true in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a polynomial equals zero for all values of $x$, it is an identity, then all its coefficients are zero.
For example, in this case $(A+B)x+A-5B=0 \implies A+B=0 \& A-5B=0$.

Similarly, if $Px^2+Qx+R=0, \forall x\in R \implies P=Q=R=0.$
But if $Px^2+Qx+R=0$ only two values of $x$, then it is an equation giving us $x_1, x_2=\frac{-P\pm\sqrt{Q^2-4PR}}{2P}.$

Comment: Thanks for the answer.